# scipy : robust linear model not converging for very simple case?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am currently working the robust linear model of statsmodels.
It works relatively well, except for very simple case such as this one, where I try to fit a simple model y = 10.x

I assume thre is a convergence issue somewhere. How could I prevent this ?

```
from statsmodels.robust.robust_linear_model import RLM as sm_RLM
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant as sm_add_constant

x = np.arange(0,10,1)
y = np.range(0,100,10)


model = sm_RLM(y,sm_add_constant(x))
result = model.fit()
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Patrick

Comment: What isn't working? What errors, if any, are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue is that I got no error, The ipython console is simply freezing...